# javascript classes in netbeans

Tags: javascript, class, netbeans

I'm using the newer class definitions in javascript but I can't get netbeans to recognize them. Is there some way to update the code highlighting in netbeans? For example the code below gets marked as wrong right now:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Comment: Current stable release (8.1) does not support ES6, but there are Dev builds ( http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/ ) which you can download with support of ES6

Answer (score 0):

Change your project's setings of javascript version to ECMAScript 6. In the IDE, it will pop up an error, you can use the auto fix on it.

Comment: I was on the latest release, as ladar stated above, 8.1 doesn't have ES6, you have to get one of the dev builds